# Http request failed after site migration - server issue

Tags: php, linux, http

So I have a website built in php and it was working perfectly on one server, I then moved the website to a server I have on Digital Ocean and am running into several errors, they seem to be based around http request failures while using the imagick library...

I was hoping to not to have to start debugging this from a code point of view as it was already working perfectly and would prefer to change server settings.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Imagick::__construct(): HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found .
```

I cannot figure out what differences there, on both server `allow_url_fopen` is set to on.

The php version is different, 5.520 on the original server, 5.5.9 on the new server.

The versions of imagick are the same. I am also getting some other errors using the mpdf library but I will try deal with these later (Im hoping if I can resolved the first ones these ones will also get resolved).

My question is , is there possibly any other setting on the server I should be looking out for that may be causing these php errors?

EDIT:

Just to add more information, i can get rid of some of the errors by changing the file path `https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg` to `/var/www/example/myimage.jpg` . This solves some of the errors but I would rather get the root of the issue thats causing it not to work in the first place, because I feel that its the same problem thats causing other errors.

Comment: I dunno, maybe the files don't exist where they say they do? HTTP paths can be relative/domainless, you know.

Comment: The files exist alright, i will make an edit to the post actually to add more clarity.

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to diagnose the problem because it is probably too unique (we have no access to your environment so it is hard to reproduce). Also, the question is more about infrastructure administration than about programming, and probably off-topic here.

Comment: You should never be making an http request to your own server. it's highly wasteful when you could just do a local filesystem request.

Comment: unfortunately part of the process reads html to build a pdf, so i have `<img src="mylink" />`, so in some cases i must use it I think

Answer (score 0):

The error code says it: 404, file not found. You are probably using the wrong URL.

Are you able to fetch `https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg` using a webbrowser?

On several popular linux distros, `/var/www/example/myimage.jpg` would be served at `https://www.example.com/example/myimage.jpg` instead of `https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg` with the default configuration.

[edit]

It just came to my attention that the URL is HTTPS, there is a possibility that the script is rejecting the server certificate. Try with regular HTTP - no point in using SSL if the file is on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did a `print_r()` of the image path thats being used right before the first error occurs and I can load it succesfully in a web browser (i.e. the `https://www.example.com/myimage.jpg` one)